# Fast calculation of probability distribution in board game Da Vinci Code

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

I'm interested in efficiently calculating the probability distribution over possible secret numbers given what one can observe of the opponents' hand (and your own hand) in the board game Da Vinci Code. A link to the game here: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8946/da-vinci-code

I have abstracted the problem into the following:
You are given an array A of length N and a finite set of numbers Si for each index i of the array. Now,

1. we are to place a number from Si at each index i to fill the entire array A;
2. while ensuring that the number is unique across the entire array A;
3. and for 3 disjoint subarrays A1, A2, A3 of A such that concat(A1, A2, A3) = A, the numbers in each subarray must follow a strictly increasing order;
   given all the possible numbers to form A that satisfy the above constraints, what is the probability ditribution over each number at each index?

Here I provide an example below:
Assuming we have the following array of length 5 with each column representing Si at the index of the column

```
| 6 6 | 6 6 | 6 |
|   5 |   5 |   |
| 4 4 |     | 4 |
|     | 3 3 |   |
| 2   | 2 2 |   |
| 1 1 |     |   | 
| ___ | __  | _ |
| A1  | A2  | A3|
```

The set of all possible arrays are:
14236
14256
14356
15234
15236
15264
15364
16234
16254
16354
24356
25364
26354
45236

Therefore the probability distribution over each number [1-6] at each index is:

```
 
6  0      4/14  0     3/14  6/14 

5  0      6/14  0     6/14  0    

4  1/14   4/14  0     0     8/14 

3  0      0     6/14  5/14  0    

2  3/14   0     8/14  0     0    

1  10/14  0     0     0     0    

___________   __________   ______

    A1          A2          A3
```

Brute forcing this problem is obviously doable but I have a gut feeling that there must be some more efficient algorithms for this.

The reason why I think so is due to the fact that one can derive the probability distribution from the set of all possibilities but not the other way around, so the distribution itself must contain less information than the set of all possibilities have. Therefore, I believe that we do not need to generate all possibilites just to obtain the probability distribution.

Hence, I am wondering if there is any smart matrix operation we could use for this problem or even fixed-point iteration/density evolution to approximate the end probability distribution? Some other potentially more efficient approaches to this problem are also appreciated.

Edit: By brute-force, I mean specifically enumerating all possibilities with constraint propagation like in sudoku. My hope is to obtain an accurate solution, or a approximate solution that approximates well (better than plain monte carlo), that works better than CP in terms of running time.

Edit2: The better solution I desire should have the characteristic  that it does not need to generate all possibilities to obtain or approximate the probability distribution.

Comment: Isn't 25346 valid under your conditions ?

Comment: Yeah I forgot, let me actually remove 4 from A2

Comment: How big can A get, and what running time are you aiming for?

Comment: A can be up to 26 in length with 13 possibilities at each position, the running time I am aiming for is below O(n!), perhaps something like O(2^n poly(n))

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider Constraint Propagation?

- When you assign a number to a position, that number cannot appear in any other position, so exclude that number from the remaining positions
- When you assign a number in the first column of a subarray, the second column must contain a larger value, so exclude all values that are lower or equal

With a BF approach in your example the code would generate and check `4 * 4 * 3 * 4 * 2 = 384` possibilities; with the CP approach we only generate 65 possibilities.

Here is a sample Python implementation:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, List

@dataclass
class DaVinci:
    grid    : List[List[int]]
    top     : int
    lastcol : int                   = 0
    solved  : List                  = field(default_factory=list)
    count   : int                   = 0
    distrib : List[Dict[int,int]]   = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.lastcol = len(self.grid)-1
        self.distrib = [{x:0 for x in range(1,self.top+1)} for y in range(len(self.grid))]
        self.solve_next(current = 0, even = True, blocked = [], minval = 0, solving = [])
        self.count = len(self.solved)

    def solve_next(self, current, even, blocked, minval, solving):
        found = False
        for n in self.grid[current]:
            if n not in blocked and n > minval:
                if current != self.lastcol:
                    self.solve_next(current + 1, not even, blocked + [n], n * even, solving + [n])
                else:
                    for col in range(self.lastcol):
                        self.distrib[col][solving[col]] += 1
                    self.distrib[self.lastcol][n] += 1
                    self.solved.append(solving + [n])

    def show_solved(self):
        for sol in self.solved:
            print(''.join(map(str,sol)))
                    
    def show_distrib(self):
        for i in range(1, self.top+1):
            print(i, end = ' ')
            for col in range(len(self.grid)):
                print(f'{self.distrib[col][i]:2d}/{self.count}', end = ' ')
            print()

dv = DaVinci([[1,2,4,6],[1,4,5,6],[2,3,6],[2,3,5,6],[4,6]], 6)

dv.show_solved()
14236
14256
14356
15234
15236
15264
15364
16234
16254
16354
24356
25364
26354
45236

dv.show_distrib()
1 10/14  0/14  0/14  0/14  0/14 
2  3/14  0/14  8/14  0/14  0/14 
3  0/14  0/14  6/14  5/14  0/14 
4  1/14  4/14  0/14  0/14  8/14 
5  0/14  6/14  0/14  6/14  0/14 
6  0/14  4/14  0/14  3/14  6/14
```

Comment: Well, by brute force, I mean exactly constraint propagation. (Sorry if I did not make this clear) I already had an implementation of it in c++ with many low-level optimizations including using a bitmap representation of the possibilities. I appreciate your effort, but unfortunately my intention is exactly to obtain a better solution than CP.

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea to get an approximation for the distribution is to use a Monte Carlo approach.

Set a variable `total: = 0` and a matrix `M[N][Q]` with all entries initially set to zero (`Q` is the total of numbers allowed).

Fix a positive integer `K`. Perform `K` iterations. At each iteration, for each `i` in `[1..N]`, take a random element from `Si` and fill the array `A`. When the array `A` is all filled, verify in `O(N)` if it satisfies your conditions. If so, increment by one the variable `total` and iterate through the array, incrementing the matrix entries `M[i][A[i]]` by one, for `i` in `[1..N]`.

In the end, iterate through all the elements of the matrix `M` in `O(N Q)` and divide its elements by `total` to get an approximation for the distribution.

Total time complexity is `O(N (K + Q))`.

---

You can also precalculate stuff to make the approximation more precise. For example, you can precalculate all increasing sequences in the groups `A1`, `A2` and `A3`. Put them in arrays `I1`, `I2`, `I3`. Then, at each iteration, instead of taking random elements from each `Si`, you take random sequences from `I1`, `I2` and `I3` and verify if the concatenation has no repeated elements (in `O(N)`). If so, proceed as before. The total time complexity (apart from the expensive precalculation) remains `O(N (K + Q))`.

Answer (score 0):

Start by converting all legal subarray selections into bitvectors.

E.g., for A2 we have [2,3], [2,5], [2,6], [3,5], [3,6]
[2,3] as a bitvector is 000110
[3,5] is 010100

Next, arrange your three subarrays by the number of bitvectors they have.

Next, put these in a hash for each subarray/member combination except the smallest subarray. Use the smallest set bit as the key.

```
E.g. For [2,3] in A2, we'd have {2 => 000110}
```

Note that the values of the map to be in an array since there will be multiple bitvectors for each index/element combo.

Finally,

```
For every bitvec of subarray_small:
  For every non-set bit of that bitvec
    Find the list that has that bit as a key in subarray_medium
    For every bitvec in this list
      Check if the inverse of (bitvec_small | bitvec_medium) is in the hash for subarray_large.
      If it is, we have a valid arrangement; update your frequency counts.
```

Comment: Could simplify this by ignoring subarray order.

Comment: I appreciate this optimization, sadly it is one that I have already implemented. The conclusion is that such optimization is not fast enough for my purpose, and I wish to obtain a better solution which has the characterstic that it does not need to generate all possibilities to obtain or approximate the probability distribution.